# Attaching a "policy" to a function parameter

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, binding, implicit-conversion

In some code that I am writing, I have a bunch of C++ functions that I am trying to bind to lua in a generic way. (However, this question really has nothing to do with lua, it's really a C++ design question.)

The idea is I might have a C++ function with signature

```
int my_function(lua_State * L, std::string server, std::string message);
```

for instance, and I want to be able to push it to lua and expose it to user scripts.

However, lua can only directly receive functions of signature `int (lua_State *)`. So, I have some templates which take a function pointer with signature like the above, and produce a function of signature `int(lua_State *)`, which tries to read corresponding arguments off of the lua stack, and calls the target function with the parameters if it succeeds, and signals a lua error for the user if not.

That part is working, with some work, and this question is not about how to do that. (Please don't tell me about `luabind`, `luabridge` or other existing libs, for reasons I can't go into those are not appropriate for my project.)

Instead the issue I'm having now is that sometimes I want the input parameters to have slightly different semantics.

For instance, sometimes a parameter should be optional. I specialized my template for `boost::optional` in order to handle that case. So I can tag optional parameters with `boost::optional` in the function signature and the wrapper will know that if that parameter is missing, it's not an error, and it should just pass `boost::none`. Example:

```
int my_function(lua_State * L, boost::optional<std::string>, std::string message);
```

So the `boost::optional` template is being used kind of like a "policy" for the input here, and I basically like how that is working.

Here's an issue I'm less sure about though: handling of `bool`. In lua, there is a proper `boolean` type, however, lua also has a notion of `contextually boolean`, similar to C++'s notion of `contextually convertible to bool`. In lua, the values `false` and `nil` are falsy, and all other values are truthy.

Typically, when you have a c++ function that takes a `bool`, the user will expect that they can pass it any value and that your interface will respect the `truthiness` even if it's not strictly speaking a boolean value. However, in other cases, you might really want it to be interpretted strictly as a `bool`, and for it to be a user error if they don't pass `true` or `false`.

What I would like to be able to do is tag the "strictness" policy within the function declaration, so it would look like

```
int my_function(lua_State * L, strict<bool> b, std::string message);
```

Where, `strict` is some template like

```
template <typename T>
struct strict {
  T value;
};
```

and this template really has meaning only in my wrapper machinery.

The thing that is annoying about this is that then you have to type `b.value` everywhere.

I thought about doing it like this:

```
template <typename T>
struct strict {
  T value;

  operator T & () & { return this->value; }
  operator const T & () const & { return this->value; }
  operator T && () && { return std::move(this->value); }
};
```

to allow a bunch of ref-qualified implicit conversions from `strict<T>` to references to the value.

How unsafe is this? I don't see major safety holes in this, although I've always adhered to the "implicit conversions are evil" mantra. I played around with it a little in test code and it doesn't seem to create ambiguities or problems, but there might be a clever way to make this do something very bad that I didn't think of.

If it's not a good idea, is there a better strategy than typing `b.value` everywhere, or some different way of rigging up the parameter policies that won't intrude upon the types?

Answer (score 1):

something like this should do it.

The overloads of `visit` are what do the work. Note the recursive call from the `optional` version.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <utility>
#include <iomanip>
#include <boost/optional.hpp>

// some boilerplate

template <typename T, template <typename, typename...> class Tmpl>  // #1 see note
struct is_derived_from_template
{
    typedef char yes[1];
    typedef char no[2];

    static no & test(...);

    template <typename ...U>
    static yes & test(Tmpl<U...> const &);

    static bool constexpr value = sizeof(test(std::declval<T>())) == sizeof(yes);
};
template<typename T, template <typename, typename...> class Tmpl>
static constexpr bool is_derived_from_template_v = is_derived_from_template<T, Tmpl>::value;


// i dont know much about a lua_state but I guess it's a bit like this...
struct lua_state {
    void set_string(std::size_t index, const std::string& s) {
        std::cout << "index " << index << " setting string " << std::quoted(s) << std::endl;
    }
    void set_missing(std::size_t index) {
        std::cout << "index " << index << " setting missing" << std::endl;
    }
    void set_int(std::size_t index, int i) {
        std::cout << "index " << index << " setting int " << i << std::endl;
    }
};

// policies

template<class T, std::enable_if_t<std::is_same<std::decay_t<T>, std::string>::value>* = nullptr>
void visit(std::size_t index, lua_state* pstate, T&& value)
{
    pstate->set_string(index, std::forward<T>(value));
}

template<class T, std::enable_if_t<std::is_same<std::decay_t<T>, int>::value>* = nullptr>
void visit(std::size_t index, lua_state* pstate, T&& value)
{
    pstate->set_int(index, std::forward<T>(value));
}

// special policy for optional
template<class T,
std::enable_if_t<is_derived_from_template_v<std::decay_t<T>, boost::optional>>* = nullptr>
void visit(std::size_t index, lua_state* pstate, T&& value)
{
    if (value)
    {
        visit(index, pstate, std::forward<T>(value).value());
    }
    else {
        pstate->set_missing(index);
    }
}

// helper function

template<std::size_t...Is, class Tuple>
void set_vars_impl(lua_state* pstate, std::index_sequence<Is...>, Tuple&& tuple)
{
    using expand = int [];
    void(expand{ 0,
        ((visit(Is, pstate, std::get<Is>(std::forward<Tuple>(tuple)))),0)...
    });
}

template<class...Ts>
void set_vars(lua_state* pstate, Ts&&...ts)
{
    set_vars_impl(pstate,
                  std::make_index_sequence<sizeof...(Ts)>(),
                  std::make_tuple(std::forward<Ts>(ts)...));
}

int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {

    lua_state ls;

    boost::optional<std::string> a { };
    boost::optional<std::string> b { std::string { "hello" }};
    std::string c = "world";

    int d = 0;
    boost::optional<int> e;
    boost::optional<int> f { 1 };

    set_vars(std::addressof(ls), a, b, c, d, e, f);


    return 0;
}
```

expected results:

```
index 0 setting missing
index 1 setting string "hello"
index 2 setting string "world"
index 3 setting int 0
index 4 setting missing
index 5 setting int 1
```

Comment: So, you sort of did the opposite direction I'm concerned about. You did the *pushing* direction, I'm trying to pull lua values off of the stack and convert them to C++, which is fiddly because we are going from dynamic type to static type. What I'm basically asking about is "how evil is it to make a special bool container type that is implicitly convertible to all sorts of bool references, if it will make my generic programming easier." Can a little container type like I showed easily cause dangling references / UB? I don't think so but I'm not 100% sure.

Comment: You can use a similar technique to deduce the argument types of the function you want to marshal to. Once you have deduced argument types you call the appropriate getter on the lua_state.